# What would be the correct way to add multiple views in my app?

Tags: c#

I'm working on an app which encodes text to QR codes.

Currently I have a form which does this for a single string.

[image: QR-code Generator]
<sub>(source: [fotopocket.nl](http://fotopocket.nl/fpimages/2011/08/24/168ba58eadf1d6357cb616cb16e97dc8/sample.png))</sub>

At the top I've added a `View` menu item with two subitems:

1. Single (which is what we're looking at now)
2. Bulk (which would allow a user to select an import file)

When the user selects `Bulk` I want to have a different toolstrip and input fields (but the same menu).

Should I create another form for this with the same dimensions (and menu) and switch the forms when another view is selected.

Or should I code both views in the same form somehow?

Basically I don't want to let the user notice a complete new screen is loaded.

So if I would have to go the 2 forms route I need to make sure the forms will be placed at the same position.

What would be the correct way to get this functionality?

Comment: Another common way of doing this in the UI is to use tabs.

Comment: @NickAldwin: I know. But I would like to prevent it. I personally don't like tabs. :) And I would like to make it more look like 2 separate things. (which is where I invalidate part of my question I know). That's how I roll ;)

Comment: That's fine, and in that case, UserControls are probably the way to go.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a UserControl for the content (toolstrip and input fields) for Single and another UserControl for the content (toolstrip and input fields) for Bulk.  You could add both to your single form and then show the correct one based on which menu option is selected.

This would give you some of the benefit of having two forms - your event handlers and such would be separated into each UserControl, but you would be loading the content into one user-visible form.